# Python simple UDP server does not receive message with IP options

Tags: sockets, udp

I have a simple udp server/client setup where I send a message from the client and print it on the server. This works well for a regular IP packet but the message is not received when I add an IP options header to the packet, even though I can sniff the packet using scapy.
Here's the packet without IP options

```
###[ Ethernet ]###
dst       = 00:04:00:00:04:01
src       = 00:aa:00:02:00:04
type      = 0x800
###[ IP ]###
 version   = 4L
 ihl       = 5L
 tos       = 0x0
 len       = 47
 id        = 1
 flags     =
 frag      = 0L
 ttl       = 61
 proto     = udp
 chksum    = 0x62f4
 src       = 10.0.2.101
 dst       = 10.0.4.101
 \options   \
###[ UDP ]###
    sport     = 10001
    dport     = 3478
    len       = 27
    chksum    = 0x2bd1
###[ Raw ]###
       load      = 'message from a game'
```

And here's the packet with IP options header:

```
###[ Ethernet ]###
dst       = 00:04:00:00:04:01
src       = 00:aa:00:02:00:04
type      = 0x800
###[ IP ]###
 version   = 4L
 ihl       = 8L
 tos       = 0x0
 len       = 59
 id        = 1
 flags     =
 frag      = 0L
 ttl       = 61
 proto     = udp
 chksum    = 0x5fe8
 src       = 10.0.2.101
 dst       = 10.0.4.101
 \options   \
  |###[ IPOption ]###
  |  copy_flag = 1L
  |  optclass  = control
  |  option    = 31L
  |  length    = 12
  |  value     = '\x00\x01\x00\x00RTGAME'
###[ UDP ]###
    sport     = 10001
    dport     = 3478
    len       = 27
    chksum    = 0x2bd1
###[ Raw ]###
    load      = 'message from a game'
```

And here's the UDP server:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(('', args.port))

while True:
    try:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
        print("received: %s" % data)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sock.close()
        break
```

I've been stuck on this for a few days and would love if someone could figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: just to confirm; when you say "sniff" I presume you mean on the same host that the "server" code is running on?  i.e. it's all localhost or made it across the network.  I presume you're using `AF_PACKET` to see lower layers, but what happens if you use the `AF_INET` family

Comment: Correct. I wrote a separate program to sniff packets using scapy and I ran it on the same host as the udp server. So the packet did make it to the server but somehow not received. The AF_PACKET part was just a typo. I've tried that but it didn't work either. Right now just using AF_INET and I've updated the question to reflect that

Comment: First, I don't think this has anything to do with python. You could just as easily use `nc -l -u 3478` (and remove the python tag). It seems likely to be an OS-specific issue (assuming the received packet is really valid). You don't say what OS you're using; that would help. Looking at the linux kernel source, for one, I don't see any reason why the same UDP packet with your (unknown) IP option would not be delivered to your server (again, if the packet is valid). Instead of just sniffing with scapy, I'd sniff with wireshark and ensure that wireshark thinks the packet is valid.

Comment: @DancingHippo I think it's something to do with your environment…  I can send packets with the same IP Options set (testing with Python 3.7.1 under OSX) and similar Python "server" code sees the packets as I'd expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to an incorrect IPv4 checksum. I failed to mention in the question that I'm running this in a mininet environment with custom switches. The IP options get added in transit by a switch, but the checksum wasn't updated. Once I fixed that, the packet made it to the server.

Thanks for the help and pointers everyone!

Answer (score 0):

have just been playing and the following works as a self-contained/minimal working example for me with Python 3.7.1 under both OSX and Linux

generating a valid set of IP Options:

```
from scapy.all import IPOption, raw

ipopts = raw(IPOption(
    copy_flag=1, optclass='control', option=31,
    value='\x00\x01\x00\x00RTGAME'))
```

(if you don't have Scapy, the above should generate: `b'\x9f\x0c\x00\x01\x00\x00RTGAME'`)

client code:

```
import socket
from time import sleep

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as s:
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 3478))
    s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_OPTIONS, ipopts)

    while True:
        s.send(b'message from a game')
        sleep(1)
```

server code:

```
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as s:
    s.bind(('', 3478))
    s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_RECVOPTS, 1)

    while True:
        print(*s.recvmsg(4096, 1024))
```

this should result in the "server" displaying lines like:

```
b'message from a game\n' [(0, 6, b'\x9f\x0c\x00\x01\x00\x00RTGAME')] 0 ('127.0.0.1', 46047)
```

furthermore, I can watch packets move over the network by running:

```
sudo tcpdump -i lo0 -vvv -n 'udp and port 3478'
```

at the command line, or this in Scapy:

```
sniff(iface='lo0', filter='udp and port 3478', prn=lambda x: x.show())
```

for some reason I don't actually receive the ancillary data containing the IP Options under OSX, but the data shows up in the packet sniffers.

Comment: I tried this and it worked fine on my OSX. So I started looking somewhere else and found the issue in the IPv4 checksum. I posted an answer.